# jQuery .load() method opens html in new window instead loading it into the specified container

Tags: jquery, html

The problem is,when I load the page from the server and immediately click on a link from the `<ul>` menu,instead of loading the requested html inside the `#stores-container` it opens new window,but if I wait about 5-10 seconds for the page to load completely,there is no problem.

jQuery:

```
 $('.countries-menu ul li a').on('click', function(e) {                 
  e.preventDefault();                                
  var url = this.href;
  $('.countries-menu ul li a').attr('id', '');
  $(this).attr('id', 'country-selected');                        
  $('#stores-container').empty();  
  $('#stores-container').load(url);             
    });
```

HTML:

```
<p class="message">Select your country</p>                
<div class="countries-menu">
    <ul>
       <li><a href="Stores/Australia.html">AUSTRALIA<span>&gt;</span></a></li>
       <li><a href="Stores/Brasil.html">BRASIL<span>&gt;</span></a></li>
       <li><a href="Stores/France.html">FRANCE<span>&gt;</span></a></li>
       <li><a href="Stores/Germany.html">GERMANY<span>&gt;</span></a></li>
       <li><a href="Stores/United-States.html">UNITED STATES<span>&gt;</span></a></li>
    </ul>
</div> 

<div id="stores-container">
</div>
```

Comment: I don't see any reason it would be in a new window, but the 5-10 seconds thing tells us that your jQuery code isn't being run until **very** late in the page load process, perhaps in response to the `load` event on `window`? You'll want to run it sooner, by putting it in a script tag at the bottom of the page and not using any event (no `load` or `ready`), or by using jQuery's `ready` if you can't put the script tag at the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enclose your js code like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('.countries-menu ul li a').on('click', function(e) {                 
  e.preventDefault();                                
  var url = this.href;
  $('.countries-menu ul li a').attr('id', '');
  $(this).attr('id', 'country-selected');                        
  $('#stores-container').empty();  
  $('#stores-container').load(url);             
    });
});
```

`$(document).ready()` waits until the page DOM has been loaded and your page is ready to run javascript codes...

Comment: Alternatively you can just put the script at the bottom of the page, right before the closing </body> tag.